# How Do I remove strategies from strategy tester in tradingvew?

Tags: tradingview-api, strategy-pattern

I've tried several strategies and now I want to delete them all but it is no way to do it and no help or youtube or google can answer that. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

To delete such strategies you can use Object Tree on the right side panel (4th vertical tab from the top)

[image: Object Tree]

Answer (score 0):

On the upper right hand where the indicators and inputs can be modified, you will find the list of strategies applied, there you can delete them.